# Does Drupal 7.87 support JQuery 3.6.x

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to update jQuery for Drupal 7.87 to version 3.6.x. The jQuery_update module (7.x-3.0-alpha5)installed and the highest JQuery version I can pick from the dropdown list is 3.3.

Does anyone know if Drupal 7.87 support JQuery 3.6.x? If yes, how can I upgrade it properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `jquery_update` allows to use "recent" versions of jQuery within Drupal but does not provide the latest versions because the changes tend to break Drupal 7 core JS.

A solution is to "side load" the newer version using the module [jQuery Multi](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) :

> jQuery Multi allows you to load an extra version of the jQuery library
> in parallel to Drupal's version, without conflicting with Drupal's
> version.

For instance, if you're loading jQuery-3.6.0, the alias will be `jq360`, and you can use it in your scripts by wrapping your code as follows :

```js
(function($){
  // Code here 
  // ....
})(jq360)
```